# How can i create an toggle button using react mozilla forms

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema

I'm trying to make a form using [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form)

I need to create a toggle button. To do this I use the following Schema and UiSchema :

```
const Schema = {
  customCheckboxComponent: {
      type: 'string',
      title: 'toggle button'
  } };

const UISchema = {
  customCheckboxComponent: {
    "ui:widget": (props) => {
        return (            
            <label className="switch">
                <input type="checkbox"  
                className="col-xs-12 custom"
                title={props.title}
                value={props.value}
                onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event.target.value)}/>
                <span className="slider round"/>
            </label>
        );
           };
```

And I'm using the css provide [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp) :

I failed to get the state of this toggle button. It's as if the state of my toggle button doesn't change !

**Can some one please help me on this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem on changing :

```
onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event.target.value)}
```

by

```
onClick={() => props.onChange(!props.value)}
```